# My Xcode only supports 3.1.2 not IPhone OS 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

What can I do?? I just upgraded my iPhone OS but now my Xcode can't
run things on it.

(and the newest Xcode on the apple site is like a beta version or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest SDK is 3.1.3.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action#

Comment: You're right 3.2 has a new XCode.  But there's also the 3.1.3 update linked to here by kubi.